# space of simple loops in the plane

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

Consider the space $S$ of smooth free simple (non-self-intersecting) loops in the plane $\mathbb{R}^2.$ By Grayson's theorem, $S$ is connected, but is more known about its topology? Is it known to be contractible (or known NOT to be contractible)? By contrast, the set of self-intersecting loops in not connected, but of course one can ask the same question about the connected components.

**EDIT** To answer @RyanBudney's question, parametrized or not is fine, and oriented or not (as @Ryan asserts, the answers are different depending on the setting, but I would be curious to know the whole set).

Comment: What is your definition of a loop?   The homotopy type depends on whether or not you parametrize it, or if not, whether or not its oriented or not.  If you take the space with parametrizations then it has the homotopy type of the orthogonal group $O_2$.  Without parametrizations or orientations, it is contractible.

Comment: @RyanBudney See the edit. I would love to know all possible answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The space of smooth embeddings $S^1 \to \mathbb R^2$ has the homotopy-type of $O_2$.  Denote this embedding space by $Emb(S^1,\mathbb R^2)$.

The proof goes like this.   Let $Emb(D^2, \mathbb R^2)$ be the space of smooth embeddings of the 2-disc in $\mathbb R^2$.  There is a locally trivial fibre bundle (due to Palais) given by restricting the embedding to the boundary circle
$$Emb(D^2, \mathbb R^2) \to Emb(S^1, \mathbb R^2)$$
It is onto by the Schoenflies theorem, and the fibre is the group of diffeomorphisms of $D^2$ which restrict to the identity on the boundary, $Diff(D^2)$.  This group is contractible by Smale.  So $Emb(S^1,\mathbb R^2)$ and $Emb(D^2,\mathbb R^2)$ have the same homotopy-type.  But by the linearization process (equivalently, the with-parameters version of the tubular neighbourhood theorem), $Emb(D^2,\mathbb R^2)$ has the homotopy-type of the linear subspace, which is $O_2$.

If you think through this argument you'll see everything is equivariant enough so that you can mod out by parametrizations to show $Emb(S^1,\mathbb R^2) / Diff(S^1)$ is contractible, as $Diff(S^1)$ also has the homotopy-type of $O_2$ (Smale uses this in his proof).

So other than ODEs, the main theorems we're using is Schoenflies and Smale's paper on the homotopy-type of $Diff(S^2)$.

Comment: What is the "with-parameters version of the tubular neighborhood theorem"?

Comment: Define a tubular neighbourhood of a closed submanifold $M$ in $N$ as a smooth embedding of a disc-bundle over $M$ in $N$ such that the zero section is $M$ and such that the image is a neighbourhood of $M$ in $N$.  Then the space of all such embeddings has the homotopy-type of the space of linear automorphisms of the bundle.  So the idea is to think of an embedding of $D^2$ in $\mathbb R^2$ as a tubular neighbourhood of the image of $0 \in D^2$.

Comment: I see. Is there a reference for this? A quick google search can't find it...

Comment: The first place this was written down at this level of generality (as far as I know) was in Cerf's dissertation: Topologie de certains espaces de plongements, Bull. S.M.F., tome 89 (1961) 227--380.  But the proof is fairly straightforward. Take the uniqueness of tubular neighbourhoods proof from the Hirsch textbook, and then  just observe that the proof generalizes to this pretty much immediately. The main additional ingredient is just the solution to ODEs depends smoothly on the initial condition (provided the initial condition is varied smoothly).

Comment: Cool, will try to digest!

Comment: @IgorRivin. A related question popped up in my mind while reading this. Is it possible to use Grayson's result instead of the differential topology in the proof ? It seems to me that using a normalized curve shortening flow, one should be able to define a retract from $Emb(S^1,\mathbb{R}^2)$ to the space of parametrized circles in the plane, would this do the job ?

Comment: @ThomasRichard that was precisely the underpinning of my question! My guess is "yes", but one  question (maybe "the" question") is what would it take to show that the flow is a retraction?